# How to escape slashes in command line argument (file path) in Java?

Tags: java, command-line, escaping, command-line-arguments, slash

Please note I'm developing this using NetBeans under Windows. I'm also running JDK 1.8.

The program takes a few arguments, via the command-line. One argument is a file path. The user might type `-i C:\test`. How do I escape the slash? Nothing seems to work right.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, ParseException {
        // Simulate command line execution
        String[] arguments = new String[] { "-i C:\test" };

        // Create Options object
        Options options = new Options();

        // Add options input directory path.
        options.addOption("i", "input", true, "Specify the input directory path");

        // Create the parser
        CommandLineParser parser = new GnuParser();

        // Parse the command line
        CommandLine cmd = parser.parse(options, arguments);

        String inputDirectory = cmd.getOptionValue("i");
        String escaped;

        // Gives error of "invalid regular expression: Unexpected internal error
        escaped = inputDirectory.replaceAll("\\", "\\\\");

        // This does not work
        File file = new File (escaped);
        Collection<File> files = FileUtils.listFiles(file, null, false);

        // This works
        File file2 = new File ("C:\\test");
        Collection<File> files2 = FileUtils.listFiles(file2, null, false);
    }
}
```

I tried replaceAll but, like it says in the code, it does not compile and it returns an invalid regular expression error.

I know best practice is to use File.separator, but I honestly have no clue how I can apply it to a command line argument. Maybe the user might type a relative path. The file path the user references could be on any drive, as well.

How do I escape the backslashes so that I can loop through each file with FileUtils?

Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: FYI forward slashes (`/`) work just in Java, e.g. `new File("C:/dir/foo")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your replacement

```
escaped = inputDirectory.replaceAll("\\", "\\\\");
```

to

```
escaped = inputDirectory.replaceAll(Pattern.quote("\\"), Matcher.quoteReplacement("\\\\"));
```

Since you are mimicking the argument within your program, take in account that

```
 "-i C:\test"
```

Will actually be a `tab` (i.e \t) in between `C:` and `est`

the correct way would've been:

```
 "-i C:\\test"
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes, even though I escaped the string, in the debugger, the `Value` is `C:\test` and the `String value` is `C:     emp`. So, the FileUtils lines of code are breaking because it can't find a directory corresponding to the String value, I'm surmising. In short, the replaceAll is not escaping the backslash. What are my options? Enforce the user to use double backslash? Replace the backslash with a forward slash in the code?

Comment: Change `String[] arguments = new String[] { "-i C:\test" };` to `String[] arguments = new String[] { "-i C:\\test" };`

Answer (score 2):

> but I honestly have no clue how I can apply it to a command line
>   argument.

If your problem is how to pass command line arguments, You may either use java command in windows command prompt as follows.

```
cmd> java Test C:\test1
```

Or if you want to pass arguments in netbeans under project properties -> run
and  then add each parameters in arguments field as shown below.

[image: How to pass arguments]

Comment: Thank you. This is helpful. One of my problems is I know `File.separator` is best practice, because it's OS independent. But I don't know how I could apply that to an command line argument, since I don't have control over what the user types.

Comment: Alternatively, You may simply use / instead of  \ as in both windows and linux  /  would work.