# How to pass a file as an argument to .jar file in command line?

Tags: java, command-line, jar

I want to run my .jar file in the command line and I have to pass 4 arguments to it, two from them are .txt files. I have the .jar file in "Exercise" directory and in the same directory I have the other directory with the .txt files. When I pass 
"input/grammar.txt" as an argument, I get FileNotFoundExeption.

```
$ java -jar Parser.jar ["input/grammar.txt"] ["input/lexicon.txt"] ["S"] ["a sentence"]
```

the current directory is where I have the folder "input"

Comment: Show the exact command you are using, and maybe we can give some pointers.

Comment: Please post your code, and the exact terminal command used to run it. Check out [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to escape slashes in command line argument (file path) in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29523089/how-to-escape-slashes-in-command-line-argument-file-path-in-java)

Comment: Hint: when you execute `cat input/grammar.txt`, the cat command doesn't start from the directory where the cat command is located to find the file. It starts from the current directory, i.e. the one you get when executing `pwd`. The same goes for java. The location of the jar file is completely irrelevant. So pass an absolute path, or a path relative to the current directory, as you would do for any other executable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know the answer, I just don't need to use the brackets. Now it's fine

```
$ java -jar Parser.jar "input/grammar.txt" "input/lexicon.txt" "S" "a sentence"
```

Comment: I saw it somewhere in the internet. I couldn't find any proper explanation how to pass arguments...